# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: Received a label value of 83193 which is outside the valid range of [0, 128)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, embedding

I tried to build a model (for simple chatbot), but i stuck on Embedding layer.
I have X_train shape = (100082, 1307) --> questions
y_train shape = (100082, 1307) --> answers
Where 1307 is my maximum length of padded sequences

Below is my code:

```
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(total_tokens, 128, input_length=max_seq_length),
    # Bidirectional(LSTM(150)),
    # Dense(total_tokens, activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50)
```

But, when i was training the model, there was an error appeared like below:
Received a label value of 83193 which is outside the valid range of [0, 128).

How should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises from your label `y_train` contains integers larger than the specified interval `[0, 128)`, because your output size of your `Embedding` layer is set to `128`.

Let's illustrate this with a simplified example. Here I reduce the shape from `(100082, 1307)` to `(1000, 1307)`:

We use a random generator to create the `y_train` tensor as follows:

```
y_train = tf.random.uniform(shape=([1000, 1307]), minval=0, maxval=127)
```

Here we test for 10 epochs:

```
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(total_tokens, 128, input_length=max_seq_length),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

Here is the output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding_1 (Embedding)     (None, 1307, 128)         128000    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 128000 (500.00 KB)
Trainable params: 128000 (500.00 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
32/32 [==============================] - 4s 124ms/step - loss: 10.5185 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
32/32 [==============================] - 5s 152ms/step - loss: 10.4612 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
32/32 [==============================] - 4s 116ms/step - loss: 10.4123 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
32/32 [==============================] - 4s 116ms/step - loss: 10.3636 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
32/32 [==============================] - 6s 175ms/step - loss: 10.3126 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
32/32 [==============================] - 4s 120ms/step - loss: 10.2577 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
32/32 [==============================] - 4s 119ms/step - loss: 10.1967 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
32/32 [==============================] - 5s 152ms/step - loss: 10.1267 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
32/32 [==============================] - 4s 119ms/step - loss: 10.0431 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
32/32 [==============================] - 4s 119ms/step - loss: 9.9369 - accuracy: 7.6511e-07
<keras.src.callbacks.History at 0x7de0b88f0ee0>
```

In this example, the model runs without errors.

However, if the upper limit of the generator is set to `200` (larger than 128):

```
y_train = tf.random.uniform(shape=([1000, 1307]), minval=0, maxval=200)
```

An error occurs:

```
Received a label value of 199 which is outside the valid range of [0, 128).
```

Therefore, you should ensure that the labels in `y_train` fall within the valid range specified by the output size of your `Embedding` layer.